# Why is BloCListener in Flutter not saving state, and there's a setState() issue during authentication?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bloc

I am implementing a Login authentication on my Flutter App using Chopper and the BLoC system. My full code is [here](https://github.com/ZiyueQian/MobileAppDemo). The BlocListner in the LoginForm works well, which can navigate me to the HomePage after authentication, but there are 2 issues:

1. When I kill the app on the emulator and restart, it would not remember the state of the Login, so a user would have to sign in again.
2. An error would appear for 2 seconds after the user is authenticated, during the navigation process.

Issue 1:
Here is what I have for main.dart:

```html
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setupLocator();
  runApp(MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
    BlocProvider(create: (BuildContext context) {
      return DispatchBloc();
    }),
    BlocProvider(create: (BuildContext context) {
      return HistoryBloc();
    }),
    BlocProvider(create: (BuildContext context) {
      return LoginBloc();
    }),
  ], child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  LoginBloc loginBloc;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Dispatch Executive App',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
                fontSizeDelta: 1.5,
              )),
      //         home: LoginPage(),
      routes: {
        '/': (context) {
          return BlocListener<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
            cubit: loginBloc,
            listener: (BuildContext context, state) {},
            child: BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
              builder: (BuildContext context, LoginState state) {
                if (state is LoadedLoginState) {
                  print("loaded log in from home!");
                  return Home(token: state.login.token);
                } else {
                  print(state);
                  return LoginPage();
                }
                //return Home();
              },
            ),
          );
        },
        '/home': (context) => Home(),
      },
      //     home: LoginPage(), //change this for testing
    );
  }
```

Issue 2:
[This issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMvZn.png)  appears for 2 seconds after the authentication is successful and the navigator is leading to the Homepage
And this is what I have for the Login Form. The BlocListener and BlocBuilder work fine here!

```html
BlocBuilder(
                  cubit: loginBloc,
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is LoadingLoginState) {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                    }
                    if (state is LoadedLoginState) {
                      print(state);
                      print("in login form");
                      print(state.login.token);
                      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home');

                      return Text("Success " + state.login.token);
                    }
                    if (state is ErrorLoginState) {
                      return Text("Error" + state.error);
                    } else {
                      return SizedBox(width: 20.0);
                    }
                  },
                ),
```

Please help! Thank you so much.

Comment: You want to go in automatically second time onward without login again? Is that your need?

Comment: For second point, I navigated couple of times but not getting any error. When you are getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

For first issue, you should save the key in phone memory. For that you can use `shared_preferences` package from flutter.

Here is the example.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SharedPreferences Demo',
      home: SharedPreferencesDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class SharedPreferencesDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  SharedPreferencesDemo({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  SharedPreferencesDemoState createState() => SharedPreferencesDemoState();
}

class SharedPreferencesDemoState extends State<SharedPreferencesDemo> {
  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  Future<int> _counter;

  Future<void> _incrementCounter() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    final int counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;

    setState(() {
      _counter = prefs.setInt("counter", counter).then((bool success) {
        return counter;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _counter = _prefs.then((SharedPreferences prefs) {
      return (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("SharedPreferences Demo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<int>(
              future: _counter,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  default:
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                    } else {
                      return Text(
                        'Button tapped ${snapshot.data} time${snapshot.data == 1 ? '' : 's'}.\n\n'
                        'This should persist across restarts.',
                      );
                    }
                }
              })),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For the second issue,